# How to schedule stop vertex (ai-platform) notebook everyday in specific time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I want to force stop vertex (ai-platform) notebook everyday in specific time?

can u tell what is the best practice for it?
is there a minimal solution for this

(maybe it can be attach into the init script in advanced mode when creating the notebook)?

can u assist please?

thanks

Comment: Could you provide more details, overview of your jobs? As I understand you want to stop notebook on specific time. It might be tricky as depends what you are doing in your notebook. In documentation [Shut down a Notebooks instance](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/shut-down) you can find information that before shutting down the notebook, you should stop all running process for opertations which needs to be done before shut down:

Comment: `It is important to stop all running processes in case there are operations that need to complete before you shut down your Notebooks instance. For example, I/O processes that are writing to disk.`
As bery basic solution you could just stop Playbook VM using `gcloud compute instances stop <vmName> --zone <yourZone>` and start it using `gcloud compute instances start <vmName> --zone <yourZone>` and use `Cron` to specify time when it needs to be executed and how often. Please provide more details of your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to develop your own script.

1. Create a crontab job which defines the time you want to shut down the VM.
2. Create a script that will be launched by crontab job #1

[Example:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567955/automatic-shutdown-at-specified-times)

```
30 23 * * * root shutdown -h now
```

When you create a new instance you can use: `post-startup-script` to install it. This parameter is executed only once after Notebook [installation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/notebooks/environments/create#--post-startup-script).

If you already created some instances, you can use native Compute Engine metadata, using `startup-script` [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux#order_of_execution_of_linux_startup_scripts).

The script could be something as simple as `shutdown now`

Comment: There are better alternatives now to this.approach. idle shutdown feature coming in h1, idle shutdown in Google.Manage notebooks and Compute Engine scheduling